# Javascript Regex match everything after last occurrence of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match everything after (but not including!) the last occurrence of a string in JavaScript.

The search, for example, is:

```
[quote="user1"]this is the first quote[/quote]\n[quote="user2"]this is the 2nd quote and some url https://www.google.com/[/quote]\nThis is all the text I\'m wirting about myself.\n\nLook at me ma. Javascript.
```

**Edit:** I'm looking to match everything after the last quote block. So I was trying to match everything after the last occurrence of "quote]" ?  Idk if this is the best solution but its what i've been trying.

I'll be honest, i suck at this Regex stuff.. here is what i've been trying with the results..

```
regex = /(quote\].+)(.*)/ig; // Returns null 
regex = /.+((quote\]).+)$/ig // Returns null  
regex = /( .* (quote\]) .*)$/ig  // Returns null
```

I have made a JSfiddle for anyone to have a play with here:

https://jsfiddle.net/au4bpk0e/

Comment: I don't understand what you want to match. The last occurence of *what* string in your string?

Comment: Sorry your right, I'm trying to match everything after the last quote...

Comment: Then why use regex at all? Use substring with lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to match everything up until the last `[/quote]`, and then get anything following it. [(example)](https://regex101.com/r/uR0pO9)

```
/.*\[\/quote\](.*)$/i
```

This works since `.*` is inherently greedy, and it will match every up until the last `\[\/quote\]`.

Based on the string you provided, this would be the first capturing group match:

```
\nThis is all the text I\'m wirting about myself.\n\nLook at me ma. Javascript.
```

But since your string contains new lines, and `.` doesn't match newlines, you could use `[\s\S]` in place of `.` in order to match anything.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8pg9ggst/)

```
/[\s\S]*\[\/quote\]([\s\S]*)$/i
```

---

You could also avoid regex and use the [`.lastIndexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) along with `.slice()`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/w1y004bd/)

```
var match = '[\/quote]';
var textAfterLastQuote = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf(match) + match.length);
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = "Results: " + textAfterLastQuote;
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `.split()` and then get the last value in the array:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ugz2vsw5/)

```
var textAfterLastQuote = str.split('[\/quote]').pop();
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = "Results: " + textAfterLastQuote;
```

Comment: You sir.. are a hero! Excellent work. Much appreciated. Hopefully users will pick up this title off Google looking for similar things and also thank you for your answer.

Comment: #TIL: "_`.*` is inherently greedy, and it will match every [match] up until the last `\[\/quote\]`._" That's a heck of a trick. Thank you.